# Let's Encrypt certbot - add a new domain to certificate

Tags: https, lets-encrypt

I have certbot installed and it created a certificate for a few domains that I host and that's working - I got a single certificate that covers all the domains. Now I want to add a new domain to the certificate. I saw the the domain roots are listed in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.com.conf` and I added the relevant entry to the domain there (under the `[[webroot_map]]` section). I then ran

`certbot-auto renew --force-renew`

Which renewed the certificate (verified the certificate issue date in the browser), but the newly added domain is not listed in the certificate.

Where do I need to add the domain in order to get it added to the certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to add a new domain or subdomain to an existing certificate as part of the renewal process (see certbot on GitHub for confirmation of this - [issue #2230](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2230)). The solution is to create a new certificate using the same syntax you used originally and adding your new domain with the -d flag.